# Facing issue with the RGB color in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, rgb, uicolor

I am using free online sites to select the RGB color . There are a lots of sites which provides the color picker . I have used at least 4 to 5 sites to check the RGB value.

Issue is I am not able to set the proper RGB values to my controls. It displays right on the website but display very different on iphone/simulator . I am using below method.

```
  [UIColor colorWithRed:230/255 Green:230/255 Blue:230/255 alpha:1.0];
```

Is there any difference in the RGB value for web sites and for Xcode or something . . Can someone refer me to the link where I can pick some colors and set the RGB in iPhone .

Comment: Are you always getting black for this code?

Comment: @taskinoor : not all the time black color really , got the answer check the post below by Karim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use,

```
  [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255 green:230.0/255 blue:230.0/255 alpha:1.0];
```

Mind the integer division in C, when both operands are integer.